# Why do objects end up stopping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

This might a dumb question, but why macroscopic object stops their motion when a resistive force is applied to them? By stoping, I do not mean why the force reduces the speed of the object by stealing its energy. Let me explain.

Imagine you have a damped pendulum (using the small angle aproximation):
$$
\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} +\gamma \frac{d\theta}{dt} +\frac{g}{l}\theta = 0
$$
If we assume an underdamped pendulum, and plot the angle with respect to time, we have:
[image]

as we see the oscilation amplitude decreases exponentially, but never is exactly zero. If you now go to real life, you will see that at one point in time, it will be completely stopped. Other example that comes to my mind is the Euler Disk, which spends lots of time moving but suddenly stops completely (same as with the pendulum).

Is there some physics behind this? Is the amplitude just $0$ when this instant comes, or is this just an ilusion because our eyes cannot percieve this small oscilations? What elements take place into the stopping of the pendulum (heat, friction, etc.)?

Comment: In practice, does it really matter?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the actual oscillations of a real pendulum do not match the mathematical model of a damped pendulum for small amplitude oscillations simply means that the mathematical model has a limited range of applicability - which is true for almost all mathematical models. Nature has no obligation to fit our models, especially those based on a fairly simplistic analysis of the scenario.

Possibly for small oscillations additional forces that we have previously ignored - such as friction at the pivot - become significant. If these forces are, say, constant rather than proportional to the speed of the pendulum then they could cause the oscillations to stop sooner than we expect from the simple model. Or, ultimately, oscillations become so small that the are indistinguishable from "noise" due to vibrations of the pivot, air currents etc. - which again is not included in the simple model.

Comment: I saw/heard something of someone making the point that, according to similar math in the OP, nothing we say every truly dies out; that the sound waves we produce are always out there. Don't push your models farther than they can go!

Answer (score 0):

In real-life system, the concept of "zero" could be often replaced by "sufficiently close to zero", especially when dealing with measurements of continuous quantities.

The definition of "sufficiently close to zero" is up to you, to the applications you're designing, the phenomenon you're examining, and what you could accept as "zero", s.t. values below that have negligible or non-measurable effects (the choice of instruments should follow all the considerations about the nature of the system, the scales involved in the problem, and the precision required, including the "sufficiently close to zero" $\sim$ "zero" equivalence).

Some external disturbances (noise, air turbulence, whatever...) may have also influence on the "close to zero" dynamics of the system, that you forgot to include in your model,

\begin{equation}
  I \ddot{\theta}(t) + c \dot{\theta}(t) + g \ell \theta(t) = M_n(t) \ .
\end{equation}

It's possible to evaluate the noise response of the system, once you have a model of the noise $M_n(t)$. If you don't have it, you can usually model it as a white noise; sometimes, some low-pass or band-pass filter models are available (and established in literature) for well-known models.

*Updating..*